# Need to upload images to a mdb database

Tags: database-design

I have a site called www.centuryautosd.com
they will be adding in their new cars as they come on the lot.  I've got the admin area done but I'm stuck on how to enable them to upload their pictures of the cars.  If you can help me I would greatly appreciate it.  I told them the site would be done today...

If you need the password for the admin area, let me know.
www.centuryautosd.com/admin

thanks!

Comment: There's not anything in here anyone can answer, since you haven't given any specific information on your implementation; tools, languages, anything.

Comment: Even with specific information, you want someone to do your job for you, and that should usually involve money.

Comment: Hiring a designer who knows how to do something besides check the glow and shadow boxes next to the layer styles in Photoshop would also be a good idea. That just looks like a jar of pee.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of a database are you using? I see most of the pages are classic ASP. If this is a new site, why aren't you using ASP.NET?

I see a generic picture of a car in the inventory section, where are you storing that image?

The username and password would help to see what is in the admin section.

Comment: I just saw that you are using mdb. Since you are in a hurry, I would recommend creating an image directory, uploading the images into that directory and storing the image location into your db. Whatever method you are using to display the db contents can take that location and retrieve the image from the directory. It's not the most correct answer but it will work and won't take long to implement.

Comment: I'm here in Murrieta!  I see that you are in Temecula.  Thank you for your answer.  Let me see what I can do.  I'm a newby and appreciate your kindness.  Is it possible to reach you directly?

Comment: We were all newbies once. Do a quick google search to find some classic asp file upload code (should be easy to find). Let me know if you can get that far.

Comment: yea, this looks a little over my head.  Would you be interested in a side job?